# Nativescript, push notification with Big View Styles

Tags: android, nativescript

How can I achieve the big view styles 
(https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) 
in nativescript with this plugin: https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin

I also opened an issue here, but no resposne:
https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin/issues/139

I Installed the NativeScript push-plugin and I use a simple php code (https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017) to send messages.
Everything is work well except that I don't know how to configure the push-plugin to send big messages.

Comment: The post lacks a concrete description of the problem, code samples, explanation of what the user has attempted to do.

Comment: @pkanev I modified the description.